# How MS Excel shows exactly as Open Office XML?

Tags: excel, openxml

My question is how excel can show as Open Office XMl.
For example :  my excel shows 218108.76 but xml shows 2960318.5100000002
I want to make excel show 218108.76, how to achieve that ?
I tried this:

1. change number digits to 15. excel shows 218108.760000000000000
2. File -> Options -> Formulas, set Maximum Change: to 0.0000000001

all these are failed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting "2960318.5100000002" from?

Comment: unzip xlsx using zip tool like 7-zip. add open xl->worksheets->Sheet1.xml